# Forward TCP Traffic With Port Translation and Retain Incoming Public IP

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, port-forwarding

I have two servers.  Windows has 1 NIC, Ubuntu has 2 NICs:

```
Server   NIC  Service  Listening Ports
-------  ---  -------  ---------------
Windows   1   IIS      80, 443
              mySvc    300            <--------------------------------\
Ubuntu    1   nginx    80,443                                          |
          2            80,443,300     forward w/ port translation to --/
```

My users need to connect to Windows port 300 to run my app.  Many companies only allow outbound traffic on ports 80 and 443, so some users cannot connect using any other port.  I cannot configure `mySvc` to listen on port 80 or 443 unless I spin up another Windows server, which I do not want to do.

In added NIC2 to a Ubuntu server, setup DNS to point to NIC2, and forward ports 80, 443, and 300 to Windows port 300.  Now all users **can** connect through any company firewall.

**Problem**: Windows sees the inbound IP of the forwarded traffic as the Ubuntu NIC1 IP address, instead of the user's IP address.

**Question**: How can I change my configuration files to pass the user's IP through in the port forwarding/port translation, so Windows see the user's public IP?

**My Configuration**: (IP addresses changed for privacy)

```
Server   NIC  Public IP  Private IP      Interface               Listening Ports
-------  ---  ---------  --------------  ----------------------  ---------------
Windows   1   1.2.3.4    192.168.23.112   Local Area Connection  80,443,300
Ubuntu    1   1.2.4.5    192.168.24.112   eth0                   80,443
Ubuntu    2   1.2.5.6    192.168.20.164   eth0:0                 80,443,300
```

On the Ubuntu server:

```
$less /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0.cfg

auto eth0 eth0:0
allow-hotplug eth0 eth0:0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
netmask 255.255.240.0
gateway 192.168.16.1
```

When we assign an IP address to `eth0:0` in the above `eth0.cfg`, the server takes several minutes to boot, and port forwarding doesn't work.  So, only `eth0` shows as configured in `ifconfig`:

```
$ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr **:**:**:**:**:**
          inet addr:192.168.24.112  Bcast:192.168.31.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
```

The port forwarding is done using a boot-cron bash script:

```
$less /etc/init.d/ipforwarding

#!/bin/bash
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -d 192.168.20.164 --dport 300 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.23.112:300
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -d 192.168.20.164 --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.23.112:300
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -d 192.168.20.164 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.23.112:300
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
#iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 300 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.20.164
```

When the forwarded traffic arrives on port 300 of the Windows box, the inbound IP address is `192.168.24.112`, which is Ubuntu NIC1, even though DNS points users to Ubuntu NIC2.  If I add `#` to the `MASQUERADE` line and remove `#` from the following line, then the traffic that arrives on the Windows server has the IP address `192.168.20.164`.  So the difference between `MASQUERADE` and `SNAT` makes sense.  But both of these change the IP address during the `NAT` operation.

I want the user's public IP address to be forwarded to Windows port 300, whenever traffic hits Ubuntu NIC2 on ports 80, 443, or 300.  Any advise would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

To use SNAT, you would need to make the Linux server the default router for the Windows server.  This is not a recommended solution.

A common solution for this problem is to proxy the traffic on the Linux server.  Have the proxy add a header with the external IP, or rely on the X-Forwarded-For header.  This will require the software on Windows to process that header with the external IP.  Many applications that are commonly proxied, have a setting to do this automatically, possibly with an application specific header.